# How to solve java.io.IOException: lseek failed: ESPIPE (Illegal seek) when read PIPE in android?

Tags: java, android, pipe

I am developing in Android. I try to implement **PIPE** , and I read the PIPE file like the following code:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
               case R.id.iat_recognize_stream:

                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        while(true){
                            try{
                                File vSDCard = null;

                                vSDCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

                                File vPath = new File( vSDCard.getParent() + "/legacy/rcfifo" );
                                // Connect to the named pipe
                                RandomAccessFile pipe = new RandomAccessFile(vPath, "r"); // "r" or "w" or for bidirectional (Windows only) "rw"

                                // Read response from pipe
                                String string_data= pipe.readLine();
                                byte[] byte_data = string_data.getBytes();
                                Log.d(TAG,"test log");


                                if(false){
                                    pipe.close();
                                }
                            }
                            catch(Exception e){
                                Log.d(TAG,"test Exception = " + e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();

            break;
        }
    }
```

And in the following log , it will show **`java.io.IOException: lseek failed: ESPIPE`**.

```
D/IatDemo: test Exception = java.io.IOException: lseek failed: ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
D/IatDemo: test log 
D/IatDemo: test log 
D/IatDemo: test Exception = java.io.IOException: lseek failed: ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
D/IatDemo: test Exception = java.io.IOException: lseek failed: ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
```

**Question 1:**

How to solve java.io.IOException: lseek failed: ESPIPE (Illegal seek) when read PIPE in android?

**Question 2:**
How to print all byte data in hex via Log ?

Comment: Use a `BufferedReader` around a `FileReader`.

Comment: @EJP Hi , Can you explain more detail ? Thanks!!